# How to use an external file in a FTP file

Tags: reference, ftp, passwords, include, external

I have a FTP file to connect a FTP site.

```
ftp -i -sc:\PATH\batchFile.txt IP.IP.IP
```

This files call a second file file, which contains user name and pass.

```
Username
PAss
```

And I want to use this credentials for another file. 
How can I use  an external command to use & reference that credential file for multiple FTP operations?

Comment: What "another file"? What do you mean by "external command"?

Comment: Yes. I meant an external command which is in another file..

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. Maybe you should include some example of what you want to do.

Comment: I do not know what kind of example shall I give. But shortly, I just want to avoid typing same code or same syntax over and over again. Instead, I want to put those commands in a single file and call it whenever I want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a username/password in a file , it is better to use ssh keys and the secure version of ftp based on ssh which is **sftp**

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sftp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+6.2-RELEASE&format=html

If you are on windows, then I believe winscp also provides a scriptable sftp command line client
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting

Comment: While this is true, you cannot assume that the OP has an SFTP access.